# What is the most recent epistolary novel written in English that consists entirely out of back and forth letters between two characters?

Tags: history-of-literature, epistolary-novel

This question probably has a somewhat unusual backstory, which is perhaps worth describing before asking the question. It hopefully clarifies and motivates the question itself.

A couple of months ago, I asked the [following question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/21119/back-and-forth-emails-and-letters) on Open Data (Beta) Stack Exchange.

> For a research project, I am currently looking for datasets that
> consists of large amounts of e-mails, text messages, or OCR-processed
> letters that were written as part of a conversational exchange between
> two people.
>
> There are quite a few open datasets that include a (significant
> amount) of emails. For instance, one has the [Enron dataset](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/), the [Jeb Bush dataset](https://github.com/hical/sample-dataset),
> and the [Hillary
> Clinton dataset](https://wikileaks.org/clinton-emails/). However, these datasets are not exactly what I'm
> looking for.
>
> I'd like to have a dataset that consists of a large amount of
> (written) conversations between exactly two people. The emails should
> alternate between these two people, with one email (or letter or text
> message) for each person, each time.
>
> **Question**: do such open datasets exist? If so, where can I find them?

Unfortunately, it yielded little attention, and no answers thus far. I also aimed at asking a similar question on Open Source SE, but [soon learned](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/928/asking-a-question-about-an-open-source-dataset-of-digitized-correspondence/929?noredirect=1#comment2214_929) questions of that kind were not welcome on that SE venue.

The research project in question entails analyzing written correspondence by means of techniques from the field of artificial intelligence. The goal is to identify missing messages among a chain of letters (or e-mails) that have been sent back and forth by two people. The messages may be missing because they were deleted or destroyed, either accidentally or on purpose.

It turns out that finding appropriate datasets that were generated through the correspondence between two actual people is not easy. Such datasets often have restrictions imposed on them, either because of copyrights or because of issues pertaining to the privacy of the correspondents and the people they mention in their writings.

Recently, I therefore thought of approaching this challenge from a somewhat different angle. Instead of trying to obtain a dataset that consists of texts written by people in the real world, I will aim at obtaining and analyzing a dataset that consists of fictional letters exchanged between two people.

A natural place to look is the [epistolary novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistolary_novel) genre. Although I have looked into the wiki article on the subject, I am by no means an expert on the topic (my educational background lies in mathematics and data science). It seems to me that most of the epistolary novels consist of fictional letters written by more than two people. Moreover, it appears the genre was more in vogue in the 19th century.

This is somewhat tricky, because I strongly suspect the AI methods work best if I work with a dataset that consists of written texts that are (a) written by only two (albeit fictional) people, and (b) written in a manner that is as "modern" as possible. It also helps if the novel is written in English. Each letter or email should be a reply to the previous one. This is where my question comes from.

**Question**: What is the most recent epistolary novel written in English that consists entirely out of back and forth letters or emails (written correspondence) between two characters - if such novels still exist?

In case such novels aren't written anymore nowadays, I'd like to hear the most recent example of such a novel. If they *are* still being written, I am interested in a recent example - preferably the most recent one before this question was originally posted (July 3, 2023).

Comment: Hmm. The only problem I can see with this question is that "most recent" potentially creates a moving target, where a correct answer may become wrong if a new book is published, unless the genre has completely disappeared since the 19th century. Recommendation questions are off-topic here, so you couldn't rephrase it as "what are some recent ...", but maybe you could make the question slightly broader by asking *if such novels still exist*, requesting that a "no" should be backed up by showing the last book in the genre and a "yes" should be backed up by showing a recent book in the genre?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Fair enough, I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I see a lot wrong with this approach. Some of those "missing" emails in the real world weren't emails. The people met, or spoke on the phone, or otherwise exchanged information that they clearly refer to in the emails, but have no corresponding message. That circumstance will not occur in a book. Also, real emails often have older messages trailing down inside newer ones, but in a book none of that will be included or printed.

Comment: @KateGregory I am aware information between two people can be exchanged through means different than emails. In this case, my aim is merely to demonstrate one could find out emails were missing, in case these people have not communicated with one another through other means. Although you make some valid points, I hope we can concentrate on the question itself, which pertains to the epistolary novel. There is another time and place for discussing the validity of the methods I'm planning to employ.

Comment: Why the need to turn fictional? Editions of correspondence (i.e. letters) between two persons are published in abundance.

Comment: @henryflower If you have some examples of collections of recently published, (OCR-)digitized, back-and-forth letter correspondence publications or datasets, please let me know! I've found some examples of books in which the letters sent by one person are collected, but not many with two people answering one another continuously.

Comment: [This TV tropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EpistolaryNovel) is a good start. It has several more recent examples. I might also mention *This Is How You Lose The Time War*, which is only four years old.

Comment: I would advise caution, though: when using free or open-source datasets for training, you are unlikely to incur any additional obligations, but the law is unsettled right now, and using copyrighted works for model training may end up obligating you to pay royalties at some point in the future or even become illegal in some countries. By using copyrighted works, you might expose yourself to significant risks, particularly if you do not have the money to pay an army of lawyers.

Comment: If the restriction to email correspondence is relaxed then other possibilities become available. One of the richest alternatives has to be the commonly used genre of dialogue between two characters, e.g., Plato's dialogues or Diderot's use of same...just to name two examples.

Comment: This question is essentially asking for an open-ended list. If I identify a work published last year, another work meeting the criteria could be published this year, leading to another answer. There is no definitive answer possible, and as such it [violates a Stack Exchange guideline](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers).

Comment: @verbose the definitive answer is the latest epistolary published before the original posting date of this question, which consists of only one possible book. See also Rand al'Thor's suggestion, which I incorporated in the question